# Can you use pg_connect in PHP to use ONLY local unix-domain sockets?

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, unix

Okay, this is something I've been banging my head on for a few weeks now, so just bear with me. When I set up my postgres database, I wanted to connect to it only through the local Unix socket. Just like how I set up my MySQL database, and subsequent PHP scripts I wrote for it. Thus, the bottom of my pg_hba.conf file looked like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
#host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I was, and still am, able to interface with my db via the psql command-line utility, and do anything I need to do without issue. However, when I tried to write a simple PHP script to connect to the db, it would always fail:

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "postgres";
$dbuser = "postgres";
$dbpassword = "####";
$conn_string = "host=$dbhost dbname=$dbname user=$dbuser password=$dbpassword";
$dbconn = pg_connect($conn_string);
if($dbconn)
{
        echo "<p>Win!</p>";
}
else
{
        echo "<p>Connect failed!</p>";
        exit();
}
pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

I was absolutely dumbstruck for weeks as to why PHP wouldn't establish a simple Unix socket connection, especially after writing quite a few scripts with the mysqli library for my MySQL db that used local connections! However, I finally un-commented the line associated with the loop-back address, and like magic it suddenly worked! This indicates to me that when 'localhost' is passed as the host parameter of pg_connect, it uses the loop-back interface, rather than just the local Unix socket.

It's not the end of the world, but is there a way to use PHP in a way so that it connects via a local Unix socket, or does it not support this type of connection with postgresql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `host` in the connection string to the value of the directory that holds the unix socket.

So if the socket is at `/var/run/postgresql/psql.sock` then try:

`pg_connect("host=/var/run/postgresql dbname=..etc...");`

Other comments on the PHP docs page for `pg_connect` indicate that you can also leave out the `host` key/value completely and it will work - but I haven't tried.:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-connect.php

Comment: Since it's using `libpq` connection strings I can confirm that `libpq` lets you omit `host` entirely and it'll use the default unix socket directory `libpq` was compiled with. This isn't necessarily the same one your PostgreSQL is configured to use (though it usually is), so it's a good idea to be explicit.

Comment: I've tried omitting the host argument, and the script still doesn't connect. I installed postgres from the postgres repositories using yum. According to the documentation, the socket file should be at '/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432'. I confirmed that file exists on my system. I swapped that value for what was in my $dbhost variable, and the script still doesn't run as of this moment.

Comment: @sirjames2004: it's not the entire socket filename, it's just the directory, e.g. `pg_connect("host=/tmp user=foo password=bar");`. Also you need the client-side error message when `pg_connect` fails.

Comment: I tried using /tmp for the host argument, but it still didn't work. I've decided this isn't worth the trouble. My senior sys admin at work tells me the loop-back interface should be enabled in pg_hba.conf anyway. Thanks for all of your feedback guys.